# Python How to check if a function is available in a imported module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I imported a new function called `pvlib` through anaconda prompt using `pip install pvlib`.

Now I have imported `pvlib` in file.

```
import pvlib
```

Now I am trying to use a function called `pvlib.ivtools.fit_sde_sandia` as given below. But it is giving error.

```
snd_fit = pvlib.ivtools.fit_sde_sandia(lit_v,lit_i)
```

Present output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-ac0f1e9b01b7>", line 1, in <module>
    snd_fit = pvlib.ivtools.fit_sde_sandia(lit_v,lit_i)

AttributeError: module 'pvlib' has no attribute 'ivtools'
```

Comment: You can see all attributes with `dir(pvlib)`. This is most likely a case of having a `pvlib.py` file that's masking the actual module.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks. I got this output for your function. ['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 '_deprecation',
 '_version',
 'atmosphere',
 'clearsky',
 'irradiance',
 'location',
 'modelchain',
 'pvsystem',
 'singlediode',
 'solarposition',
 'spa',
 'tmy',
 'tools',
 'tracking',
 'version']. I donot see 'ivtools' here. Is that right?

Comment: I just installed it on my system and `ivtools` is present. What version are you installing? I checked the repo and it looks like ivtools was added in the 0.7.0 release.

Comment: I installed it just now through anacondaprompt as stated in my question. I am surprised. How did you install it? In between, same function is available in `github` with `ivtools`. I downloaded the whole file. How to install it?

Comment: `pip3 install pvlib`

Comment: What version of Python? pvlib 0.7.0 requires >= python3.5

Comment: `pip3 install pvlib` did not work. `pip install pvlib` worked. Does it makes difference?

Comment: Python 3.6 I am having

Comment: @jordanm Any idea what could be wrong here at my side?